# How to preserve type definitions of a function while exposing it on global namespace (object)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Basically I don't want to import lodash functions is each file. I want to expose them on some global namespace(e.g. L). I don't want to import whole of lodash library but only import few functions. I am trying following things but then I loose type support.

```
interface Lod {
  head: Function
}

interface Window {
  L: Lod;
}

import head = require('lodash/head');

window.L = {
  head: head
}
```

So now when I use head() then IDE gives me intellisense support (showing errors as no argument is passed but I should give an array) and also i get compilation errors from typescript saying I am passing incorrect parameters to head (which is correct).

But when I use window.L.head() then I don't get any help from intellisense(no errors) and typescript also don't give any error at compilation (which is wrong, I should get errors).

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Which information are you missing from intellisense? If you're not getting any compiler errors then it should be fine and your intellisense should pick up on things.

Comment: Hi @NitzanTomer, Thanks for looking into this. If i use head('wrong', 'parameters') then i get intellisense help and error's to from typescript compiler on command line (which is right). But when I use window.L.head('wrong', 'parameters') then i don't get errors intellisense or command line (which is wrong...i should get since I am passing wrong arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `head` directly the compiler can check the definitions in it which is why the intellisense work and you're getting errors.

But your definition of `Lod.head` is a `Function`, which is why the compiler is fine with you passing whatever arguments.

You should do this:

```
import head = require('lodash/head');

interface Lod {
    head: typeof head
}
```